# sub-div flys out of main div even after applying clearfix with correct relative & absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

just got a question regarding relative & absolute positioning and applying clearfix to the main container cos I've written the code and it's not behaving as I expected.

Structure-wise this is a simple page about product history. nav-bar with drop-down menu at the top across the screen, then a big hero image across the screen, followed by a few paragraphs and a simple footer, that's it.

here's my problem:
I need to put 3 components in the hero image area - the hero image itself, one title word on the top left corner and one logo on the top right corner. What I've done is: I created a div and used the hero image as background image. I set the position value of the div to relative. I created another div to hold the title word and set the position to absolute, using top and left to give it a location. Following the same logic, I created another div to hold the logo and set it to float right, with position set to absolute and top and right to give a location. I've applied clearfix to the main div and everything looks ok on my screen (resolution 1280 x 1024) until I saw it on the wide screen(1680 x 1050) --- the logo is not on the hero image! It's to the right side of the hero image.

What caused this? I thought by putting 2 divs inside the main div and applying clearfix, the three will "get together" and act as one and won't separate... Is it because I haven't written any code for responsive layout? Or was it because I shouldn't have used the hero image as the background? Would this problem be solved if I used z-index instead to specify the stack order of hero image, logo and title word?

Below is my code and any help would be much appreciated!

```
<div id="history-content" class="clearfix">
    <div id="history-image-text">HISTORY</div>
    <div id="stamp">
        <img src="./images/logo.png">
    </div>
</div>



#history-content {
    background-image: url('./images/heroimage.jpg');
    min-height: 307px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

#history-image-text {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#stamp img {
    width: 10%;   /*not sure I'm doing the right thing here either*/
    height: 40%;  /*not sure I'm doing the right thing here either*/
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    top: 20px;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: float has no effect on absolutely positioned elements, as far as i know...

Comment: "I created another div to hold the logo and set it to float right, with position set to absolute and" - i don't see another div with position absolute. only one divs has absolute positioning in shared code.

Comment: hi Tilwin, there's "position:absolute" in both the #history-image-text and #stamp img sections...thanks.

Comment: @TilwinJoy yes I'm not 100% clear about floating and absolute position. Are you saying they can't be used together? so it's "either-or"? thanks.

Comment: hope the answer explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

- Absolutely positioned elements are taken out of normal flow, hence doesn't affect the size of their parent.
- Since they're out of normal flow, `float` has no effect on them (*as far as i know*)
- Absolutely positioned elements shrink wraps to fit it's contents unless `width` and `height` is set explicitly or stretched using the `top`, `right`, `bottom` & `left` properties.

<strike>Now your parent div `#history-content` doesn't have any height set, and all of it's content of   are absolutely positioned, So [it's not visible](http://jsfiddle.net/B6Hf8/1/) (*height 0*)</strike>

applying a proper height for the parent seems to [fix the issues](http://jsfiddle.net/B6Hf8/) for me.

*Side note: unlike what you think, you don't have two absolutely positioned`<div>`'s, `#stamp img` absolutely positions the `<img>` inside `div#stamp`, for the same reason mentioned above, `div#stamp` is also invisible (height 0) you'll get the same result with and [without it](http://jsfiddle.net/B6Hf8/2/). And [without floats](http://jsfiddle.net/amtxf/)*

Comment: thanks a lot and my apology - I did have min-height:307px in the #history-content section. that's the height of the hero image. and I had the problem I described above on a 1680x1050 screen with that line of code in place. Could you please look at it again?

Comment: @user3603298 i checked the fiddle i shared on an imac  with `1920x1080` res, and nothing is going outside the background… is this the actual css or are there more missing pieces..?

Comment: I replaced "min-height:307px" with "height:100%" and "width:100%" and the hero image changed it's size from 1214x307 to 1214x121...no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, float doesn't have an effect on absolute positioned elements, and so technically you don't need clearfix in this case.

I'm not exactly sure why your logo is positioned outside the outermost container #history-content, but you could try to put a border around the #history-content to further troubleshoot.

**EDIT:** Maybe check your hero image dimension, is it smaller than 1608px in width?

```html
<div id="history-content">
    <div id="history-image-text">HISTORY</div>
    <div id="stamp">
        <img src="./images/logo.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

I've changed your CSS below

```
#history-content {
    background-image: url('./images/heroimage.jpg');
    min-height: 307px; /*set whatever minimum height you wish*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

#history-image-text {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#stamp {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 10%; /*set width of image in containter instead*/
    height: auto;
}

#stamp img {
    max-width: 100%; /*image width will not stretch beyond 100% of container*/
    height: auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5L9WL/3/

Comment: hi thanks for your kind help. yes the width of the hero is 1214px, which is smaller than 1608px. Could that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Yes very likely. #history-content background does not stretch or repeat - as set by your css. if you want the background to auto expand, add background-size:cover; to #history-content